# MongoDB's Node.js Driver installation fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have **nodejs** and **mongoDB** installed on 32bit winXP veteran. And I am trying to link them. 
In the [mongoDB docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/node-js/#node-js-driver) its stated that the easiest way is by this command:

```
npm install mongodb
```

Unfortunately it throws the following exception:

```
"Failed to replace env in config: ${APPDATA}"
```

I tried to point the **NODE_PATH** variable to the "npm\node_modules" folder but this does not solve my problem. 
What additional configuration am I missing?

Comment: ? https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/2840

Comment: @WiredPrairie
I've already tried the suggestions in this topic with no success: 
**APPDATA** -> "C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Application Data"
**NODE_PATH** -> "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm". And Im setting them in 'My Computer -> Right Click -> Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables'.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end just ran the cmd not as Administrator but simply from my account and the command("npm install mongodb") worked as expected.

After that I uninstalled it since this was kind of weird. And again tried as Administrator and it failed again. And again succeeded with my account. So I left it be.